# Parsing a JSON response from an API in C#

Tags: c#, json, httpwebresponse

I called REST API and was able to put the JSON response received back in a String using:

```
string vResp = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd();
```

Below is the result of vResp from `Console.WriteLine`

```
{
  "Response" : [ {
    "UserID " : "23123213",
    "UserName " : "dms"
  }, {
    "UserID " : "542515",
    "UserName " : "ark"
  }, {
    "UserID " : "56546",
    "UserName " : "oneim"
  }, {
    "UserID " : "33336536",
    "UserName " : "cyberx"
  }, {
    "UserID " : "7563624",
    "UserName " : "bt"
  }, {
    "UserID " : "1221414",
    "UserName " : "azure"
  } ],
  "count" : "6"
}
```

I want to parse each `UserID` and `UserName` and insert each record in a table but not able to parse correctly. I tried different codes and I am able to separate `Response` and `count` but not able to reach one level below. Can anyone please help in this?

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: newtonsoft have a great tool called [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Remove `Encoding.Default`. It seems to work just by accident, since you only have base ASCII chars in the JSON. API usually return UTF8 encoded (the default encoding) data.

Comment: Which version of .net are you using?

Comment: Please, provide us the REST calling implementation so we can have a big picture of how you are doing things. This allow us to provide a more accurate solution :)

Comment: HI, welcome to SO. Please [edit] and include your current solution. Also, please read [ask]. 
Also, if you are using .NET Core 3.x or .NET 5+, you can use the built-in `System.Text.Json` namespace for deserializing json strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Create C# class that match with your vResp json result and then then use JSON.NET to deserialize the JSON data to created C# class objects.

You may refer this tool http://json2csharp.com/ to generate C# class based on your Json data.

Here is the code sample how you can parse Json data into C# class.
User userObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(vResp);

Now User will have parsing information and you can insert into table.

Comment: Yes - I am doing the same but still having issue `var vJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(vResp);` this is my code but when I do `                    Console.WriteLine(vJson.Response.ToString());` I do not see the Response part of the JSON object.